# need to merge the price from E column to D column as like 21187 row ,

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

there are 8k rows are there in the database need to separate the price and insert into D column.please do check the screenshot
is there any formula ??

[check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t05mv.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, but more importantly, I don't even know if you're asking an Excel or database question.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: I am having set of excel contains 8k data I need to separate the price(Rs 192.50) in E column and added into D column (manually ) but is there any possibility to have a formula to sort it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need more examples but you can use an UDF in column D, or loop column E occupied cells and apply the function to the column E values, and output result into column D. There are lots of assumptions in the below, including that you want the first match only. It applies a regex (search pattern applied to the cell text) that looks for qualifying cost data as starting with `Rs.`, then 1 or more numbers, then optional `"."` and optional more numbers.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TransferCosts()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range("E1:E14").Value
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To UBound(arr, 1))
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, 2) = arr(i, 1)
            arr(i, 1) = GetCost(arr(i, 1))
        Next i
       .Range("D1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetCost(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    Dim arr() As String, i As Long, matches As Object, re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\bRs\.\d+(\.[^\s]\d+)?\b"
        If .test(inputString) Then
            GetCost = .Execute(inputString)(0)
        Else
            GetCost = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Regex:**

[image: regex]

---

**Full explanation:**

**Pattern:**

```
/
\bRs\.\d+(\.[^\s]\d+)?\b
/
gm
```

`\b` assert position at a word boundary (`^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W`)

`Rs` matches the characters `Rs` literally (case sensitive)

`\.` matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)

`\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

"`+`" Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**1st Capturing Group (`\.[^\s]\d+)?`**

`?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\.` matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)

Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\s]`

`\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

`\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

`\b` assert position at a word boundary (`^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W`)

*[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/wv9wSi/4)*

---

**References:**

Some great YouTube videos on regular expressions by Shiffman at 
[The Coding Train](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman/search?query=regex)

Comment: can you provide any youtube link

Comment: its working but if the E column has Rs.1,234 means its reflecting Rs.1 ?

Comment: Yes as it excludes the character ",". It looks for ".". Is "," also valid instead of "." ? Or in that case should it return nothing?

Comment: i don't get it sir

Comment: With  Rs.1,234   Should the result be  Rs.1,234   or  blank?

Comment: I am asking a question. What is the expected result in that case? The regex would be changed to include "," or perhaps to lookahead and exclude if "," present.  Depends on what result you expect.

Comment: \bRs\.\d+(\,[^\s]\d+)?\b this could be the output Rs.2,294 and actual output would be Rs.2,294.00

Comment: Ok. So you have amended as you need it?

Comment: i have changed the code \bRs\.\d+(\,[^\s]\d+)?\b    ' \ , ' instead of '\ .' but the result is coming like Rs.2,345 but it should be as Rs.2,345.00 . '.00' is not coming what should i do

Comment: \bRs\.\d+([,.][^\s]\d+)?(\.\d+)?\b

Comment: sir, I had one more query with a sentence like What is ACILOC 300mg Tablet used for? ACILOC 300mg Tablet is used for the treatment.  The following result should be ACILOC 300mg Tablet is used for the treatment. [?after the question mark  should be present ] there are 43k rows in a column